# MYSQL : many-to-many problem

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

[image]

i'm trying to filter product with their subcategories :
for example : 
if subcategories = (1,3,4)
and if this is subcategory_product :

[image]

how can i get the products with subcategories id=(1,3,4) ??!! plz help
in this case i should get the product with id 62 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To limit to only one join you and avoid subqueries can do something like this:

```
select p.* from product p
join subcategory_product sp on 
    (sp.product_id = p.id and sp.subcategory_id in (1,3,4))
group by p.id
having group_concat(subcategory_id order by subcategory_id separator ',') = '1,3,4';
```

Comment: Note that this only returns products with precisely those three subcategories. If the product has those three and one more then it will not return.

Comment: @mendosi Wasn't this the requirement? "subcategories id=(1,3,4)" I interpreted this as product has subcategories 1, 3, 4 and only 1, 3, 4.

Comment: @KárolyNagy just slightly different interpretation, that is all.

Answer (score 1):

One approach (you will need to test this for performance if the dataset is large) is this:

```
Select `sc1`.`product_id`
  From `subcategory_product` As `sc1`
  Join (Select `product_id` From `subcategory_product` Where `subcategory_id` = 3) `sc3`
    On `sc1`.`product_id` = `sc3`.`product_id`
  Join (Select `product_id` From `subcategory_product` Where `subcategory_id` = 4) `sc4`
    On `sc1`.`product_id` = `sc4`.`product_id`
  Where `subcategory_id` = 1
;
```

Basically, you're scanning the `subcategory_product` table once for each of the values, and then doing an `INNER JOIN` on the results to only get rows back where all three exist.